# What is the Easiest/Best Way to Get an Array of Values from an Array Collection?

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, actionscript, collections

I have an Array Collection with any number of Objects. I know each Object has a given property. Is there an easy (aka "built-in") way to get an Array of all the values of that property in the Collection?

For instance, let's say I have the following Collection:

```
var myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
    {id: 1, name: "a"}
    {id: 2, name: "b"}
    {id: 3, name: "c"}
    {id: 4, name: "d"}
    ....
);
```

I want to get the Array "1,2,3,4....". Right now, I have to loop through the Collection and push each value to an Array. Since my Collection can get large, I want to avoid looping.

```
var myArray:Array /* of int */ = [];

for each (var item:Object in myArrayCollection)
{
    myArray.push(item.id);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the underlying `Array` object from the `ArrayCollection` using the `source` property, you can make use of the [`map`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/Array.html#map()) method on the `Array`.

Your code will look something like this:

```
private function getElementIdArray():Array
{
    var arr:Array = myArrayCollection.source;
    var ids:Array = arr.map(getElementId);
    return ids;
}

private function getElementId(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):int 
{
    return element.id;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't avoid looping, just avoids you writing the loop.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) the ArrayCollection does not keep the keys separate from the values.  They are stored as objects in an underlying array.  I don't think there is any way to avoid looping over them to extract just the keys since you need to look at every object in the underlying array.

Comment: While it's true that each object must be examined, an explicit loop is not necessary.  The Array class offers convenience methods to help situations like this.

Comment: The loop just has a different author.  Still it's best to use the framework provided mechanism absent some other reason.